# Alienware M17xR3 only 3gb/s speed with SSD

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata

I have an alienware M17xR3 and a Samsung 830 SSD, I've had it for a while now but today I've installed Samsung Magician, and I've noticed the message that my maximum speed is 3gb/s and 6gb/s is not supported.

My laptop does support the 6gb/s speed, I've read about the issues with the module 0 bay, so I moved it to the module 1 bay, but nothing changed.
My bios has the latest firmware, I have AHCI mode on and the SSD has it's latest firmware.
How can I make it go at 6gb/s?

Answer (score 3):

Dell intentionally disabled 6Gb/s support on these laptops (in the [A09 BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=JDM9W)) due to a controller problem that caused data reliability and SSD compatibility issues. If you want to enable 6Gb/s, you need a [hacked BIOS](http://forum.techinferno.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=28), often called "unlocked" or containing a "SATA tweak". I would leave well enough alone -- Dell disable 6Gb/s support for a reason.

Comment: Ohh now I remember, I have downgraded to the A08 bios version when I first installed the drive, I was doing now an OS reinstall and I was updating all my firmwares.
I was running on the A08 firmware until now, so I think I will downgrade back to it, it was working fine so far.
Would you recommend a hacked A12 firmware or the official A08 one?

Comment: @DoubleP90 If it was working fine before and you're willing to tolerate whatever possible risk of data loss there might be, I'd suggest downgrading to A08.